# How to fix my Android Project in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, git, project

I've downloaded my project from the server in another PC, and imported it in Eclipse, but now it does note run.

I've already cleaned the project at Project menu, and fix the projet properties in Android Tools.

I am getting these errors:

```
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".

Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

The Fix Project Properties does not works.

I think the problem is the relative path. I've got an error like res' does not exist.

Where I set this relative path in my project?

Comment: post the errors you get.

Comment: right-click on your project and select "Properties -> Java Compiler", check "Enable project specific settings" and select 1.6 or 1.7 from "Compiler compliance settings" select box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about to change 'compiler compliance level'?

You can find that - Project property > java compiler

1.6 or 1.7 may fix your problem...

Comment: Thank you. I've changed it, now I am getting this error: Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
The "Fix Project Properties" does not works.